# Time Zone JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma aplicação, onde pego Time Zone do PC.

```
var d = new Date()
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
```

Em minha situação, ele retorna 180, acredito que seja -3 Horas (180 / 3). Assim, tenho dúvidas qual a maior TimeZone e qual a menor. Em um site eu vi especificando -12 e +14 (720 e  -840). Alguém pode me confirmar estes dados, pois preciso validar um campo TimeZone.

Answer (score 2):

O número retornado pela função `getTimezoneOffset` é a diferença em minutos da hora local para UTC, ou seja, **180** é o equivalente a **GMT-3**, **-120** é o equivalente a **GMT+2** e assim por diante.

**Referência:** [Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)